# Will shorten a sentence with object complement confuse readers with adverbials?

Tags: grammar

The sentence,

> The teacher punished the student who bullied the new boy

What if I shorten it to

> The teacher punished the student bullying the new boy.

Now, will readers confuse that whether 'bullying the new boy' is describing the teacher or the student? In fact, I am confused as well. Is this object complement or adverbials?

Comment: [Will shortening [gerund noun]  a sentence do etc.]

Comment: We have whole nursery rhymes like this.  For example, The House that Jack Built.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not ambiguous.

The adverbial is normally associated with the closest noun phrase, unless context and common sense suggest otherwise. To make it describe the teacher, it would be

> The teacher bullying the new boy punished the student.

Comment: Thank you. In you sentence, does 'punished the student' describe 'the new boy', and why do you use 'punished' instead of 'punishing'?

Comment: It describes the teacher. And I use "punished" because it's a past-tense verb. The sentence is the same as "The teacher punished the student", and "bullying the new boy" just indicates which teacher.

Comment: Present tense would be "is punishing the student"

Comment: Thank you. So my sentence 'The teacher punished the student bullying the new boy.', the 'bullying the new boy' is an object complement, describing the student, right?

Comment: Right. And in my sentence, it's a subject complement.